# Why does this program hang?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following code which is seems to be lead to the infinite loop:

```
struct X
{
  void my_func( int ) { std::cout << "Converted to int" << std::endl; }
};

struct X2 : X
{
  void my_func( char value ) { my_func(value); }
};
```

What is the problem with it?

Comment: There's no program here, just two class definitions. It does not and cannot hang. In fact, it can't be run. Post real code that you are trying to run.

Comment: Most of us were able to fill in the blanks. Just sayin'...

Comment: @Igor Zevaka: Certainly. But in 9 cases out of 10 "filling in the blanks" produces a useless answer to a meaningless question. I hope this one proves to be that 1 out of 10 when it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second bit is infinitely recursive:

```
struct X2 : X
{
  void my_func( char value ) { my_func(value); } //calls itself over and over again
};
```

Prefix `my_func` with the name of the base class and you will be OK

```
struct X2 : X
{
  void my_func( char value ) { X::my_func(value); }
};
```

<strike>**EDIT** Just realised that base class `my_func`'s signature is different. C++ compiler resolves the function overload statically, that means it will pick the function that best matches the type of the argument, that's why it calls the `char` overload.</strike>

For example:

```
char cChar = 'a';

myfunc(cChar);

void myfunc(char a){} //<-- this one is called
void myfunc(int a){}

int iInt = 1;

myfunc(iInt);

void myfunc(char a){} 
void myfunc(int a){} //<-- this one is called
```

Thanks Charles Bailey. The above code does not apply in this case as `X2`'s `my_func` hides base class's `my_func`. This leaves the only solution to qualify the function with the class name.

Comment: Thanx. I thought that `my_func` is not defined at that point yet and `X::my_func` should be called.

Comment: @zilgo: It isn't defined, but it is declared. And that's all you need.

Comment: In a derived class any function with the same name but a different signature will hide the base class functions of the same name. This means that in `X2`'s member functions unqualified `my_func` _always_ refers to `X2::my_func` and never to `X::my_func`. There is no "best match" going on here. The posted "For example:" is misleading as it simply doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
void my_func( char value ) { my_func(value); }
```

You're passing the `value` which is `char` so it resolves to calling the same method with accepts a `char` parameter. It becomes an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
void my_func( char value ) { my_func(value); }
```

right there, you've written a recursive function with no base case. I don't know too much about C++, but you need to somehow specify that you want to call X's my_func, not X2's(I'm assuming that's what you want to do.)

**edit:** To fix it, you need to cast value to an int

Comment: A cast to `int` of the parameter isn't going to help. `my_func` in the derived class hides the base class `my_func`. An explicit qualification of `my_func` is needed.

Comment: Doesn't it overload it, not hide it?

Answer (score 0):

The program gets in an infinite loop.  my_func() calls itself and there's no condition to exit out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your call my_func(value) is recursive. Did you mean super::my_func(value) ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs due to hiding. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call the base class' function, i.e.:

```
struct X
{
  void my_func( int ) { std::cout << "Converted to int" << std::endl; }
};

struct X2 : X
{
  void my_func( char value ) { X:my_func(value); }
};
```

By default, the compiler uses functions within the same class if present, as there is no way for it to know which one you actually want to use. By specifying `BaseClass::Function` within a derived class' method, the compiler will explicitly create a call to that base class's method, even if you have overridden.